# How to launch MediaPlayerLauncher using device's isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I would like to simply launch the MediaPlayerLauncher task, but I would like to use media that is already on the WP7 device. From my research it seems that to use this task, one must first include media packaged as a resource, or use media that is saved in the applications isolated storage. Is there a way to only use the phone's isolated storage so that the MediaPlayerLauncher task may load using media from the default media player application (for instance if a user places music on a phone from his or her computer, that media would be recognized and loaded into the MediaPlayerLauncher). 
Basically what I would like to accomplish in the end is for the WP& default media player to load as it does when a user clicks the tab, although if the user wants to select music, the music section would load instead of the default zune section. Is this even the right task to accomplish this, and if not is there a way to use default phone functionality like this? If not, is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation seems to suggest that it is perfectly possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher(v=VS.92).aspx

The property location takes enumeration which allows Data - ie in Isolated Storage.

Create a Uri (relative) set the Location and give it a go.